# C++ partial template template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization, template-templates

I want to pass a partial template specialization to template template parameter but I'm getting an error. Im not sure why excatly this doesent work.

```
template<template<typename, int> class V, typename T, int N, int... Indexes>
class Swizzle
{
    // ...
};

template<typename T, int N>
struct Vector;

template<typename T>
struct Vector<T, 3>
{
    // ...

    union
    {
        // ...
        Swizzle<Vector, T, 3, 0, 0, 0> xxx;
    };
};
```

Error:

> 'Vector': invalid template argument for template parameter
>   'V', expected a class template 'Swizzle': use of class template
>   requires template argument list

Problem appears only on [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/58Qx9n)

Comment: What compiler and flags are you using? Is this code sufficient to repro the problem? This works for me [on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fefaa7c92d8cc73) once I add some semicolons.

Comment: Actually it works on mingw730_32.

Comment: Im using VS2019 and fixing the missing semicolon's, still produces this error. I tried pasting the rest of my code into godbolt using clang as compiler, that works so i guess this must be a VS2019 error?.

Comment: offtopic: `union` in C++ code is not a best idea. Note there is `std::variant` (c++17) which is modern version of the `union`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the class template `Vector`, `Vector` refers to both the type of this instance of the template and the template itself.

[This should compile](https://godbolt.org/z/mswtrw):

```
template<class X, int M>
using Self = Vector<X,M>;
// ...

union
{
    // ...
    Swizzle<Self, T, 3, 0, 0, 0> xxx;
};
```

I suspect MSVC is wrong here, but am uncertain.

Comment: fails on clang and gcc https://godbolt.org/z/Rox8M- but type definition in global scope works: https://godbolt.org/z/NyKfLr

Comment: @MarekR Fixed.  Just a name collision.

Answer (score 1):

Within the class with [class name injection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name#In_class_template), `Vector` might refer to both the type of this instance of the template and the template itself.

> In the following cases, the injected-class-name is treated as a template-name of the class template itself:
>
> [..]
>
> - it is used as a template argument that corresponds to a template template parameter

So Msvc is incorrect here.

Possible workaround:

```
Swizzle<::Vector, T, 3, 0, 0, 0> xxx;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/RckNuP)